Parallel Execution of Word Document Processing in C# with Task.Run()
I'm working on a C# application where I need to process multiple Word documents in parallel. Specifically, I'm trying to apply a bookmark conversion method to each document concurrently. Here's the signature of the method I'm working with:
ConvertBookMark(string introText, ConvertionNode convertionNode1, Application wordApp1, Document doc1, string docFilePath, string solnPath, string clientName, string ssoConfigModel);

To achieve parallel execution, I'm using Task.Run() but it seems like the tasks aren't running in parallel as expected. Below is a snippet of my code where I'm trying to queue each document processing task:
List<WordTaskInfo> wordTaskInfos = new List<WordTaskInfo>();
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

foreach (var item in someCollection) // Assume someCollection is defined elsewhere
{
    wordTaskInfos.Add(new WordTaskInfo
    {
        DocFilePath = item.DocfilePath,
        BookmarkName = item.BookmarkName,
        // Other properties initialization
    });

    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
    {
        Log.LogBookmark($"Creating Instance Start :{item.BookmarkName}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
        lock (wordLock) // Assume wordLock is defined elsewhere
        {
            try
            {
                var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
                var doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref item.DocfilePath, // Other parameters omitted for brevity
                );
                
                ConvertBookMark(item.IntroText, item.ConvertionNode1, wordApp, doc, item.DocFilePath, item.SolnPath, item.ClientName, item.SsoConfigModel);
                
                doc.SaveAs2(item.DocFilePath, WdSaveFormat.wdFormatDocumentDefault, false);
                doc.Close();
                wordApp.Quit();
            }
            finally
            {
                // Cleanup logic here
            }
            Log.LogBookmark($"Creating Instance End :{item.BookmarkName}", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"));
        }
    }));
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

I'm wondering if I'm using Task.Run() correctly for parallel execution, or if there's a better approach for handling parallelism in this scenario, especially considering the use of COM objects with Microsoft Office Interop. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Except from the lock inside the loop (it can not be a parallel job with this lock), it seems to be correct, but I'm not sure of how word works. Instead of a task list, you can use Parallel.ForEach(someCollection, (item) => {....})

lock in conjunction with async/Task most definitely is not going to do what you think it does.

Why do you use a lock? Your tasks wait for it to unlock to start working.

Using tasks, or any kind of parallelism, seem fairly pointless if you immediately use a lock to serialize execution again. And I would be careful when trying to parallelize word interop. It seem easy to make mistakes when using COM/interop, so I would personally stick to the simplest/safest possible code, or look for some other library that can handle word documents.

Also, if you have to, at least await Task.WhenAll instead of Task.WaitAll

And expanding Jonas' comment: do you really need to parallelize?

I used lock to prevent potential conflicts when manipulating COM objects across parallel tasks, but testing showed it might not be necessary for isolated Word instances.

I agree with the other comments, but I'd also like to add that instead of rolling your own parallel for each, just use the built in Parallel.ForEach

"it might not be necessary for isolated Word instances" - also mind that in the shown code, if your convert method throws, there won't be graceful cleanup.

@Fildor "Yes, I'm exploring alternative approaches for processing multiple Word documents in parallel that don't compromise performance. Any suggestions would be appreciated!"

Echoing what JonasH said, you really should consider using a .NET library that can handle docx documents instead of automating Word. We switched from Excel automation to an Excel library many years ago and never regretted it. It's faster, less error-prone and we can even use it in web applications and Windows services (i.e. in cases where Office automation is not officially supported).

@JonasH and Heinzi Thank you for the advice! Could you please suggest any open-source library that can handle docx documents automation?

For library recommendations -> https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

@Bisjob  Thank you for your suggestion, "After switching from Task.Run() to Parallel.ForEach(someCollection, (item) => {...}), I noticed the execution time is 01:59 minutes. While it's working, I'm looking for ways to further improve performance. Any suggestions?"

It depends of the number of doc you want to execute in parallel, but you can use a Thread pool instead of Tasks. It's way more complexe to write, but you will be able to dedicate some thread of your computer for this work.
And if you want to optimize this, first you need to get the time of all job. How long do you wait the lock (btw I hope you don't have it in the loop anymore), how long takes ConvertBookMark, how long it take to write the file, how long it takes to close the doc,... I would suggest you to edit your post or add an answer with your new code and all of this time
